# WooCommerce: Custom cart item counts by product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

I found [**this script**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/) that allows me to show cart content total above the shopping cart icon within WooCommerce:

```
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

If there are 100 items in my cart it shows 100.

What I really want is to display the count by item types. So if there are 50 t-shirts and 50 shorts, I want that 2 item types count to be displayed individually.

Does anyone knows how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Updated** - August 2018 - Lighter and compact code version.
>
> **Similar new answer:**
> [Custom cart item counts by product category in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775962/custom-cart-item-counts-by-product-category-in-woocommerce-3/51777457#51777457)

This function is made to display the cart count for a specific product category:

```
function cat_cart_count( $cat_name ) {
    $count = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( has_term( $term, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            $count += $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    // Returning category count
    return $count == 0 ? false : $count;
}
```

*You will paste the code above to the function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

For **`"shorts"`** category you will use it this way: **`cat_cart_count( "shorts" )`** and will replace `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()`.

> Note: Since woocommerce 3, `WC()->cart->get_cart_url();` is replaced by `wc_get_cart_url()`.

Customizing the snippet code with it for **`"tshirts"`** and **`"short"`** categories:

```
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d t-shirt', '%d t-shirts', cat_cart_count( "tshirt" ) ), cat_cart_count( "tshirt" ) ); ?> - <?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d short', '%d shorts', cat_cart_count( "shorts" ) ), cat_cart_count( "shorts" ) ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

As the html tag class "cart-contents" is use by woocommerce refreshed cart fragments, you might need to rename it as explained in: [Custom cart item counts by product category in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775962/custom-cart-item-counts-by-product-category-in-woocommerce-3/51777457#51777457)

Last thing in our customized snippet code, you can customize-it your way adding some text or additional things… I have replace **`"item(s)"`** by the category name.

Comment: Loic your reply worked perfect for me. Thank you very much!